# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#, excel, comexception, vba

I get the following error:

> Unable to create instance of class TestProject.TestClass. Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'D:\Automation\TestProject\OBJECT_DEFINITIONS.XLS' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct. If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.

Error Stack Trace:

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
>   TestProject.TestLibrary.GetObjectDeclarations(String sModule) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestProject\TestLibrary.cs: line 133
>   TestProject.TestClass..ctor() in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestProject\TestClass.cs: line 51

code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace TestProject
{
[TestClass]
public class TestLibrary
{
    public string[] arrObj = new string[19];
    public string[] arrConfig = new string[12];
    public string sobjfile;
    .
    .
    .
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sobjfile, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

I am wondering why is the error saying `D:\Automation\TestProject\OBJECT_DEFINITIONS.XLS` could not be found when I have `OBJECT_DEFINITIONS.XLS` stored in `C:\`

Comment: and where we can see your path to this excel file?

Comment: I am not sure. All I see is the variable sobjfile which is not assigned any path. I also tried public string sobjfile = 'C:\\OBJECT_DEFINITIONS.XLS";
but get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course you need to assing path to `public string sobjfile`. Application doesn't know where to search your file.

**EDIT:**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1","A1").Value2.ToString());

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, i thought so, but i am looking at the code from somebody else. I don't know why I was still getting the error after I assigned the path to sobjfile before. And, now it is working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Without delving deep in your code syntax (I'm not a C# programmer), and based on my experience with Selenium, try the following -

Ensure that OBJECT_DEFINITIONS.XLS is just that and not OBJECT_DEFINITIONS.XLSX.
I have run into Selenium compatibility issues with files created and saved using Excel 2007. If it is, save the excel file as an "Excel 97-2003 Workbook".